# Changing MysQL value with PHP not with user id but username?

Tags: php, mysql, userid

I am trying to make simple form where you put user_id etc. etc. and it will change in mysql, which works pretty fine but the question is, is there any way I could instead of users_ids use usernames ? thanks

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-change'])) {

    $account = strip_tags($_POST['account']);
    $value = strip_tags($_POST['value']);
    $string = strip_tags($_POST['string']);

    $account = $DBcon->real_escape_string($account);
    $value = $DBcon->real_escape_string($value);
    $string = $DBcon->real_escape_string($string);

    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET $value='$string' WHERE user_id=$account";

    if ($DBcon->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $msg1 = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                        <i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Successfully changed !
                    </div>';
    } else {
        $msg1 = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> &nbsp; Something went wrong !
                </div>';
    }

    $DBcon->close();
}
```

Comment: How is `tbl_users` structured?

Comment: Also, you're wide open to sql injection. Use prepared statements, not straight queries.

Comment: Why would you not be able to use usernames?

Comment: *"is there any way I could instead of users_ids use usernames"* ... yes, but we'd need more info on your schema.

Comment: Yes? What have you tried? It's as simple as `"UPDATE tbl_users SET field=:value WHERE user_name = :username;` - because you should be using PDO....

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, the table structure is here: https://imgur.com/bsJLsxY and I am pretty much new to this so i'll try to understand as much as possible

Comment: @cale_b also I would like to keep using MysQL instead of PDO because for now it's the only thing i understand atleast little bit

Comment: @ItzBlazik - my I encourage you this way: _Don't keep learning an outdated and insecure technology_.  Slow down, learn the right way (PDO, in my opinion), and build ALL of your knowledge and experience on that.  If you don't, you'll find yourself always building in unsafe mysql_ because you'll never want to go back and refactor all of the code you have ready done....

Comment: @cale_b yeah, i guess you're right, but since this is just pretty much testing project I would like to finish it way I started it, anyways thanks I will look into PDO right after it.

Answer (score 1):

The original MySQL extension has been removed in PHP7 and was deprecated in PHP 5.5.

Don't be intimidated by PDO though, it's actually super simple and much better.

Require this code at the start of any PHP files that need to make database queries.

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = "3306";
$dbname = "NameOfTheDatabase";
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;port=$port;";

$dbuser = "UsernameForDatabase";
$dbpass = "PasswordForDatabase";

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "set names utf8");

$database = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
```

Note that it can be improved upon drastically but for the sake of example, we'll keep things simple. Usually you would want to load this information from a protected config file.

Now let's say we want to select the user by their username.

```
$statement = $database->prepare("
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM tbl_users 
    WHERE username LIKE :username
");

$statement->bindParam("username", $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo $result->user_id;
```

Basically what we're doing here is telling PDO to store a query that we've prepared in the $statement variable. We then tell it to use [bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to replace or bind :username with the POST variable (this will take care of escaping).

After the statement is executed using [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), we have two options. The [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) function essentially takes the next (or in this case, first) returned row and stores it in the $result variable. After that, you can access the returned columns using their names, in this case, $result->user_id. However if you SELECTed the rank, for example, you would be able to access it with $result->rank.

The second option is the [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) function which works in nearly the same way, except that it takes every row returned and stores it in an array. Even if only one row is returned. That means that you'd need to access the data using $result[0]->user_id where 0 is the returned row.

```
foreach($result as $row){
    echo $row->user_id;
}
```

Or you can loop over the result array using foreach as above. One of the greatest features of PHP in my opinion.

Updating and inserting works in nearly the same way except that no rows are returned by the execute function. Instead, the amount of rows that were changed is returned.

```
$statement = $database->prepare("
    UPDATE tbl_users
    SET email = :email
    WHERE user_id = :user_id
");

$statement->bindParam("email", $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam("user_id", $_POST['account'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

$statement->execute();

echo "Rows changed: ".$statement->rowCount();
```

In that example, we're just updating the user's email address using a POST variable for the email and the account variable for the user_id. Notice that I used PDO::PARAM_INT for the third parameter of bindParam, that's just because the user_id is an integer. Usually you can get away with PDO::PARAM_STR but it's supposed to be for strings.

If you want a bit more detail by somebody far better at explaining things than me, [check this introduction to PDO out](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). Hope this gets you on the right track!

Comment: Good luck! It's a little bit confusing to get started but these are the basic concepts used in every PHP application so if you can get your head around this, you'll be on your way to mastering PHP.